# JMockit Capture and replace interface method logic

Tags: java, jmockit

How can you capture the calling of an interface method and replace the captured interface method's logic with the mocked one, using JMockit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is clearly described in "The JMockit Tutorial", here: http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/StateBasedTesting.html#interfaces

Here comes the copy-pasted example of code that mocks the `CallBackHandler` interface and provides own implementation of the `handle` method:

```
@Test
public void mockingAnInterface() throws Exception
{
    CallbackHandler callbackHandler = new MockUp<CallbackHandler>() {
        @Mock
         void handle(Callback[] callbacks)
         {
             assertEquals(1, callbacks.length);
             assertTrue(callbacks[0] instanceof NameCallback);
         }
    }.getMockInstance();

    callbackHandler.handle(new Callback[] {new NameCallback("Enter name:")});
}
```